# Pasar varios parametros a una vista en CodeIgniter 2

Tags: codeigniter

Buen dia comunidad, espero puedan ayudarme con este pequeño problema que tengo... recien comienzo con este framework y se me presento el siguiente inconveniente .
Es un sitio en el cual pretendo mostrar productos y categorias de una base de datos ... el codigo de la vista, modelo y controlador lo dejo a continuacion.
***Problema:*** Lo que quiero hacer es en la vista de productos mandar los datos de las categorias, productos y tambien paginacion, por lo que pueden ver en mi codigo tuve que separar una vista de categorias y otra de productos para lograrlo de manera temporal, pero al momento de querer meter la paginacion de productos me tope de nuevo con el problema :/ ***Resultado esperado:*** usar una sola vista de productos que tenga categorias, productos y paginacion.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Principal_ci extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->model('categorias_mdl');
    $result = $this->categorias_mdl->getCategorias();
    $cat = array('categorias' => $result);

    $this->load->model('productos_mdl');
    $result = $this->productos_mdl->getProductos();
    $prod = array('productos' => $result);

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('categorias', $cat);
    $this->load->view('principal', $prod);
    $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}

class Productos_mdl extends CI_Model {

    public function getProductos($limite=9)
    {
        return $this->db->get('producto', $limite);
    }       

}
// Fragmento de la vista de como saco los datos actualmente
<?php foreach ($categorias->result() as $categoria) { ?>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item"><?= $categoria->nom_cat ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar diferentes valores del controlador a la vista se podría crear un `array` asociativo de la siguiente forma.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->model('categorias_mdl');
  $categorias = $this->categorias_mdl->getCategorias();
  /* Agregamos la clave categorias */
  $datos['categorias'] = $categorias;
  $this->load->model('productos_mdl');
  $productos = $this->productos_mdl->getProductos();
  /* Agregamos la clave productos*/
  $datos['productos'] = $productos;
  $this->load->view('header');
  /* Pasamos los valores a la vista productos*/
  $this->load->view('productos', $datos);
  $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

En la Vista accederíamos de la siguiente forma.

```
foreach ($productos as $value) { ...} 

foreach ($categorias as $value) { ...}
```

> Como recomendación si se trata de una clase y posiblemente se use los
>   modelos en varios métodos sería mucho mejor cargarlos en el constructor de
>   la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres enviar varios datos a la vista, tienes que crear un array asociativo y enviarlo como parametro a tu vista.

Tu codigo sería asi:

```
class Principal_ci extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->model('categorias_mdl');
    $result1 = $this->categorias_mdl->getCategorias();
    $data['categorias'] = $result1;

    $this->load->model('productos_mdl');
    $result2 = $this->productos_mdl->getProductos();
    $data['productos'] = $result2;

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('productos', $data); //envias todos los datos a la misma vista.
    $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, puedes acceder a los valores que envias a tu vista con la clave del arreglo asociativo que se creo, para usar los valores de productos usas $productos, y para categorías usas $categorias.